# Mybatis batch insert/update using DB2 Merge option throwing error

Tags: sql, merge, db2, batch-processing, mybatis

I am trying to do mybatis batch insert/update to DB2 using merge option
I have opened SQLSession using option ExecutorType.BATCH;

Then i do a bunch of sql statement using merge option

```
<insert ....> MERGE INTO table
    USING ( VALUES ( ###))WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN insert when matched update   </insert>
```

Then i do
client.flushStatements();

Mybatis throws exception on this statement

```
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: XXX.xxx (batch index #1) failed. Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.go: [jcc][t4][102][10040][3.58.81] Batch failure.  The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch.
```

Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null

Comment: Does the `MERGE` work well when ran by itself outside MyBatis?

Comment: Yes, if i do merge with mybatis without batch it works fine

Comment: To eliminate the possibility of a driver-error, you should test with a *current* type-4 Db2 jdbc driver (version 4.26.14 for example), because your Db2 jdbc driver is very old and many bugs have been fixed since 3.58.61 was released. Download from IBM fix central, see versions here https://render-prd-trops.events.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads